# Mockito Matcher for a TypeReference

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a Java unit test using Mockito but am having trouble to get a matcher to work.

I want to test the following class

**CustomService.java**

```
public class CustomService {

private final ApplicationProperties props;

public CustomService(ApplicationProperties props){
    this.props = props;
}

private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
public void method(JsonNode message) throws CustomException {
    try {
        List<String> actions = mapper.readValue(message.get("actions").toString(), mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, String.class));
        System.out.println(actions);
    } catch (IOException ex){
        throw new CustomException(ex);
    }
}
}
```

I have a CustomException class

**CustomExcepton.java**

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public class CustomException extends Exception {

public CustomException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
    }

}
```

I want to test that the CustomException is thrown.  I am using Mockito.  I have tried the below but the **given** statement doesn't seem to pick up the (readValue) line of code in the method

**CustomServiceTest.java**

```
public class CustomServiceTest {

private final ApplicationProperties props = mock(ApplicationProperties.class);
private final CustomService customService = new CustomService(props);
private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Test
public void CustomExceptionIsThrown() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    given(mapper.readValue(anyString(), any(TypeReference.class))).willThrow(new IOException("This is a test"));
    String json = "{\"actions\":[\"ac1\",\"ac2\",\"ac3\",\"ac4\"]}";
    JsonNode d = objectMapper.readTree(json);
    assertThrows(CustomException.class, () ->
            customService.method(d));
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I run the test

```
Expected exception.CustomException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown..
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `mapper` seems to be a local variable, thus you can't mock it like this. You need to change this by supplying it in a different way (for example as parameter to the method).

Comment: Apologies, that was a poor copy & paste.  I was using a mock.  I've updated the code above

Comment: The example still seems to be incomplete, as now you are missing the definition of what the `mapper.getTypeFactory()` is supposed to return. Please provide a [mre], including your class/method under test and your unit test.

Comment: Ì have updated my code with a minimal reproducible example.  Hopefully that helps

Comment: I've update my answer. Your updated code makes it slightly more complex for you, as you need to inject the mock into your class under test. However having a constructor with arguments prevents you from using mockito's default mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I also met this same problem, and i find that although i mock objectMapper like "
**when(objectMapper.readValue(anyString(), any(TypeReference.class))).thenReturn(xxxx);**" but when i invoke the test,  the first param of readValue(xx,xx) is **null** which should be a String object. So, you might want to check readValue method input param again.Hope it will help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are still some issues with your example code.

- You did not inject the Mock of `ObjectMapper` into your `CustomService` class.
- As your class under test now has a args constructor, you won't be able to inject the mock into your test. You will need to adjust the constructor to pass the `ObjectMapper` from the outside or rely on `Reflections` to place the mock manually.

The general advice would be to pass the `ObjectMapper` as argument into the construtor. Doing it this way, you won't need to change the `final` on the field `mapper`.

```
private final ApplicationProperties props;
private final ObjectMapper mapper;

public CustomService(ApplicationProperties props, ObjectMapper mapper){
    this.props = props;
    this.mapper = mapper;
}
```

- You still have not defined the behaviour for the mock when the `getTypeFactory()` method is invoked. You should get a `NullPointerException` at this point (if your code actually used that mock).
   In the example below I replaced this definition by using the [`RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) option,
  which causes `mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, String.class)` to return a mock of `CollectionType`.
- The mock definition with `TypeReference` is not required, as it does not match your method parameters which are used when the `readValue` method is invoked. Instead you will have to work with `CollectionType`.
- As your method under test is `void` you will have to use the `willThrow(...).given(...)` syntax instead.

---

Here an example of a working test:
(Only works for a `CustomService` class with a no-args constructor)

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class JacksonTest {

    static class CustomException extends Exception {
        public CustomException(IOException ex) {
            super(ex);
        }
    }

    static class CustomService { 
        private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        public void method(String c) throws CustomException {       
            try {
                mapper.readValue(c, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, String.class));            
            } catch (IOException ex){
                throw new CustomException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @InjectMocks
    CustomService customService;

    @Test
    public void testCustomExceptionIsThrown() throws Exception {

        BDDMockito.willThrow(new IOException("This is a test")).given(mapper).readValue(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(CollectionType.class));
        Assertions.assertThrows(CustomException.class, () -> customService.method("x")); 
    }
}
```

---

Dependencies:

```
testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2"
testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.0.0"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9"
```

Comment: The test doesn't run for me.  I get a "Cannot resolve symbol 'MockitoExtension' "

Comment: When I click in IntelliJ to Find JAR on web, it says No libraries found

Comment: I've added the dependencies I used. The `MockitoExtension` is part of `mockito-junit-jupiter`.